# Complex irreducible representations of the Klein 4 group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, solution-verification

I wrote an answer to the following question. Can someone please verify it?

> Completely and explicitly describe, up to isomorphism, the set of all complex irreducible representations of the Klein 4 group

We know that the Klein 4 group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Firstly, we have the trivial representation, given by the homomorphism $\psi(g) = 1$ for all $g \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Secondly, we have the representation given by the homomorphism $\psi(0,0) = 1, \psi(0, 1) = -1, \psi(1, 0) = 1, \psi(1,1) = -1$.

Thirdly, we have the representation given by the homomorphism $\psi(0,0) = 1, \psi(0, 1) = 1, \psi(1, 0) = -1, \psi(1,1) = -1$

Lastly, we have the representation given by the homomorphism  $\psi(0,0) = 1, \psi(0, 1) = -1, \psi(1, 0) = -1, \psi(1,1) = 1$

We can verify that the characters of these representations are orthonormal, and hence irreducible.

Comment: This is correct, but the last sentence, though true, makes me unhappy. Forget about orthonormality; all one-dimensional representations of any group are obviously irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more complete answer would indicate how you know your list is complete. The irreps are all 1-dimensional because the group is abelian; since the sum of the squares of the dimensions equals the group order, there must be exactly four irreps.